# Creating Data Extension with other type than standard

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

On Marketing Cloud Data Extensions in **Email** -> **Subscribers** -> **Data Extensions** have type. Is there possibility to create Data Extension by API with other type than Standard (Filtered, Random)? In Data Extension SOAP documentation I don't see a 'type' property. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create filters ([FilterDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/filterdefinition.htm)) and filter activities ([FilterActivity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/filteractivity.htm)) via SOAP API, which is what 'Filtered Data Extensions' are.

Basically you would need to:

1. Create your [Target DE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm) (the one that will hold the resulting data)
2. Create a FilterDefinition that contains your filter logic
3. Create a FilterActivity that combines your FilterDefinition with your Target DE
4. Run the FilterActivity to populate your Target DE with the filtered Data.

It is just a multi step process compared to the UI Wizard that does the calls for you, but it is still possible.

To get 'Random' you would need to use SQL to gather a random data set from a source DE.

Like so:

1. Create your [Target DE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm) (the one that will hold the resulting data)
2. Create a SQL query ([QueryDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/querydefinition.htm)) to grab the random dataset you desire
3. Perform the QueryDefinition to fill in your data into the Target DE

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql) is a good source for 'random selection' queries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your way to create filtered DE and it's working but there is one problem. In subscribers -> Data Extensions in table, type is still 'Standard' and i can filter it but which is impossible with 'Filtered' DE. Can i somehow change this type when creating by API?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to create non-standard data extensions through the API. That being said, you could run activities through the API in order to mimic the behavior of those data extensions by doing something like:

1) Create standard data extension with appropriate columns using the API.

2) Create/update SQL query with the API to include your filtering conditions (or random selection from a parent DE if you need a random DE)

3) Execute Query via the API.

If you have less than 2,500 rows then you could just initialize the parent DE and run a filter part on it to return your filtered/random data set with SSJS rather than having to create/run a query. While it is possible to execute on more rows than that by keeping the request open, it's slow and probably best suited for SQL in that instance.